# How to insert letter between two letter in a text input?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a function in a module i have made, to insert letter’ s before  some specific letter ''vowel in fac'' in a text input. The text can be everything written by everybody. Can be letter, number, symbol. But for this function it will be only for letter’s.

Fist fonction.
For exemple, in the input field : (John get in2 the train.)
I want when i press on the button of my function,
that the result show : (javohn gavet avin2 thave travain)

Second function.
And make the same in the reverses procedure ,
input field :(javohn gavet avin2 thave travain)
and the after i press the button : John get in2 the train.

I have made something whit a dictionnaire in another programme and change all the letter’s in a text by another one and do the reverse, and work well. But this don’t work for what i want do to whit insertion of letter in a text.  Or i miss something….I’m new in programming, but i love this, and a lot to learn. Im a self learning….. Thank for your help or ‘’Q’’ in the good direction.

I put a picture of my code.
[the code[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SecCP.png)

this one work well for another application, but not here for what i want to do.

Comment: Please post your existing code, an example input, and your expected output so that we can comment on it.

Comment: @Selcuk  for a exemple of the  input and output is in the question, ''John get in2 train'' that is the input and the output have to be like this:'' javohn gavet avin2 thave travain.'' i will put the code in the question in a moment.  ii want to be able to place ''av'' before each vowels in a text.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend regex for this. Specifically the [sub()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub) function. If you wanted to replace every 'e' and 'i' with 've' and 'vi', you could do this:

```
re.sub(r"[ei]",lambda x:"v"+x.group(0),my_text)
```

where `my_text` is a variable containing the text input.

For your second function, it would be something like:

```
re.sub(r"ve|vi",lambda x:x.group(0)[1],my_text)
```

The way this sub() function works is that it finds every match of the regex pattern, then applies a function to get the replacement string. In the first case it adds a 'v' in front. In the second case it takes the second letter.

Comment: @ geokavel. i try the fist one to put specific letter between other and it work well! i put "av" before every vowels. For the second code i can only take one letter at the time and i want to take two, the "av" .  I  have try something like [0:1] or [0, 1] but it yelled a error.  This is my code: import regex as re


def un_code2(message3):
    my_text = message3
    mapping = re.sub(r"av", lambda x: x.group(0)[1], my_text)

    output = mapping
    return output

Comment: @geokaval. I finally made it work like this.        """my_text = message3
    pattern = r"av+"
    nstr = re.sub(pattern, "", my_text)

    output = nstr
    return output"""        so like this i can get off the letter i want in my text or word. Your fist ligne of code work very well to insert what i want.  the second one after a lot of try and search i finally made it.  Thank a lot for the hint.